# gewahrt wissen?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Was bedeutet »gewahrt wissen«? Ein Beispiel der Nutzung ist im folgenden Satz:

> Wir sind überzeugt, dass gerade Sie als Internet-Nutzer Ihre Privatsphäre **gewahrt wissen** wollen.

Mir ist nur bisher nur das Folgende aufgefallen: Be sure that something (e.g. privacy) is taken into account / observed / respected.

Comment: Der Sinn von "wahren" lässt sich schön über *integrity* transportieren.

Comment: Ich denke bei "wahren" eher an "preserve", also sowas wie "... that preserving your privacy is important to you."

Comment: Fragen, zu deren Beantwortung Kenntnisse anderer Sprachen als Deutsch erforderlich sind, sind off-topic.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, that he is asking for English or Russian should be an indication that what he really wants is to understand the phrase.

Comment: Exactly, I am happy to see an explanation or a translation in German.

Comment: Wenn man gar keine Übersetzung haben will, sondern nur wissen will, was die Phrase bedeutet, dann sollte man auch nicht um eine Übersetzung bitten, sondern genau das fragen, was man wirklich wissen will. Ich habe die Frage entsprechend editiert.

Answer (score 3):

Probieren wir's mit einem Synonym.

Für deinen Satz

> Wir sind überzeugt, dass gerade Sie als Internet-Nutzer Ihre Privatsphäre **gewahrt wissen** wollen.

sind hier ein paar andere wohlgeformte[1] Formulierungen, die das gleiche sagen:

> Wir sind überzeugt, dass Sie als Internet-Nutzer **sicher sein** möchten, **dass** Ihre Privatsphäre **gewahrt wird**.
>
> Wir sind überzeugt, dass Sie als Internet-Nutzer **sichergehen** möchten, **dass keine Eingriffe** in Ihre Privatsphäre **stattfinden**.
>
> Wir sind überzeugt, dass Sie als Internet-Nutzer **sicher sein** wollen, **dass** ihre Privatsphäre **sicher ist**.
>
> Wir sind überzeugt, dass Sie als Internet-Nutzer **davon ausgehen können** möchten, **dass** Ihre Privatspähre **nicht verletzt wird**.

Kurz:

> gewahrt wissen

heißt so viel wie "wissen, dass gewahrt wird..."

Wie man an den etwas umständlichen anderen Sätzen sieht, erlaubt *gewahrt wissen* eine kurze und darum elegante Formulierung des Sachverhalts.

Ich denke, du kannst deine Frage damit beantwortet wissen.

---

[1] "wohlgeformt" im Sinne von Syntax und Semantik. Über Stil müsste man dann gesondert reden.